# Duda código en C, no arroja resultados esperados

Tags: c

Buen dia.

Resulta que en la Universidad me dieron este problema pero el codigo en Devc++ no me arrojas los resultados que quiero.

Mi problema es este:

En una empresa con N empleados se necesita obtener cierta información. Por cada empleado se ingresan los siguientes datos: CLAVE, EDAD, SEXO y SUELDO.
a) Número de hombres.
b) Número de mujeres.
c) Número de mujeres que ganen más de $20, 000.
d) Número de hombres menores de 40 años que ganan menos de $40,000.
e) Número de empleados mayores de 50 años.

Mi codigo es este:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
/* variables */
int chombres,cmujeres,co1,co2,co3,edad,nume,sueldo;
char clave[10],sexo[10];
float i;
/* Start */
printf("=============================\n");
printf("=        -Bienvenido-       =\n");
printf("=               Negocio     =\n");
printf("=============================\n");
/* datos de entrada */
printf("Ingrese el numero de empleados: \n");
scanf("%i",&nume);
for (i=0;i<=nume-1;i+=1) {
    printf("Ingrese la clave del %f° empleado(a) ;\n",i+1);
    scanf("%s",clave);
    printf("Ingrese la edad: \n");
    scanf("%i",&edad);
    printf("¿El empleado es hombre o mujer?\n");
    scanf("%s",sexo);
    printf("Ingrese el sueldo mensual total del empleado: \n");
    scanf("%i",&sueldo);
    if (strcmp(sexo,"Hombre")==0 || strcmp(sexo,"Mujer")==0) {
        if (strcmp(sexo,"Hombre")==0) {
            if (edad<40 & sueldo<40000) {
                co2 = co2+1;
            }
            chombres = cmujeres+1;
        } else {
            if (sueldo>2000) {
                co1 = co1+1;
            }
            cmujeres = cmujeres+1;
        }
        if (edad>50) {
            co3 = co3+0;
        }
    }
}
printf("El total de hombres es de: %i\n",chombres);
printf("El total de mujeres es de: %i\n",cmujeres);
printf("Mujeres con sueldo mayor a $20,000 es de: %i\n",co1);
printf("Hombres menos de 40 años y con sueldo menor a $40,000 es de: %i\n",co2);
printf("El numero de empleados mayores a 50 años es de: %i\n",co3);
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Si me podrian decir en que me equivoque se los agradeceria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entre varios errores de lógica, fallos en el código(como falta del `&` en algunos `scanf()`, no incluir la cabecera de  para poder utilizar la función `strcmp()`(que en tu caso he utilizado `strcmpi()` para que haga las comparaciones sin tener que escribir la primero letra del sexo de la persona en mayúsculas.). Recomendable tambien iniciar las variables que uses.

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    /* variables */

    int chombres = 0, cmujeres = 0, co1 = 0, co2 = 0, co3 = 0, edad = 0, nume = 0, sueldo = 0;
    char clave[10] = {}, sexo[10] = {};
    int i;

    /* Start */

    printf("=============================\n");
    printf("=        -Bienvenido-       =\n");
    printf("=               Negocio     =\n");
    printf("=============================\n");

    /* datos de entrada */

    printf("Ingrese el numero de empleados: \n");
    scanf("%i", &nume);

    for (i=0;i <= nume-1; i++) {

        printf("Ingrese la clave del %d empleado(a):\n",i+1);
        scanf("%s", &clave);
        printf("Ingrese la edad: \n");
        scanf("%i", &edad);
        printf("¿El empleado es hombre o mujer?\n");
        scanf("%s", &sexo);
        printf("Ingrese el sueldo mensual total del empleado: \n");
        scanf("%i", &sueldo);

        if (strcmpi(sexo,"Hombre") == 0 || strcmpi(sexo,"Mujer") == 0) {

            if (strcmpi(sexo,"Hombre") == 0) {

                if (edad < 40 && sueldo < 40000) {
                    co2++;
                }

                chombres++;

            } else {

                if (sueldo > 20000) {
                    co1++;
                }

                cmujeres++;
            }

            if (edad > 50) {
                co3++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("El total de hombres es de: %i\n",chombres);
    printf("El total de mujeres es de: %i\n",cmujeres);
    printf("Mujeres con sueldo mayor a $20,000 es de: %i\n",co1);
    printf("Hombres menos de 40 años y con sueldo menor a $40,000 es de: %i\n",co2);
    printf("El numero de empleados mayores a 50 años es de: %i\n",co3);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es verdad, te lo agradezco demasiado.

Comment: @JesusOsio Me alegra que te haya servido mi respuesta. No olvides votar positivo y marcar como aceptada con el check en gris que aparece a lado de mi respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

no he probado el código pero por qué declaras `float i`. En particular lo hago de la siguiente forma

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
```